# Combinations of lists in LINQ Null if one list has no records C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists

```
var list1 = new List<int>(){ 100,101 }; 
var list2 = new List<int>(){ 200,201 };
```

**Case 1:** `list1` and `list2` have records

Required output:

```
100 200 
100 201
101 200
101 201
```

**Case 2:** `list1` have no records but `list2` have two records

Required output:

```
null 200
null 201
```

**Case 3:** `list2` have no records but `list1` have two records

Required output:

```
100 null
101 null
```

Please suggest better way than applying if else conditions.

Comment: And have you tried something?

Comment: What type is the required output? Something like a list of `Tuple<int, int>`?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `if`/`else`?

Comment: What if both lists have items, but not the same number of items?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean a "cross join" or "Cartesian join".You just need to use the `join` as,

```
var result = list1.Join(list2, x => true, y => true, (m, n) => new { m, n });
```

OR

```
var result = list1.SelectMany(x => list2, (x, y) => new { x, y });
```

OR

```
var result = from x in list1
        from y in list2
        select new { x, y }
```

If you want something else (as you can see from comments), please edit your question appropriately.